# how can i place two color pins ? 1 in red and 1 in green?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am using this sample app to make route

http://blog.kadirpekel.com/2010/05/30/drawing_routes_onto_mkmapview_using_unofficial_google_maps_directions_api/

It will call the routing api and parse the result.

Then a new layer is added above the map with the route between A and B.

My problem is how can i place two color pins ? Right now Its showing 2 red color pins. But I need 1 red and 1 green.

I am trying to work with this delegate, but its not helping me

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
            viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    if(annotation == yourFirstAnnotation)
{
MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:yourFirstAnnotation reuseIdentifier:[annotation title]];
            annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
            annView.animatesDrop=NO;
            annView.canShowCallout = YES;
            return [annView autorelease];
}
else
if(annotation == yourSecondAnnotation)
{
MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:yourSecondAnnotation reuseIdentifier:[annotation title]];
            annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
            annView.animatesDrop=NO;
            annView.canShowCallout = YES;
            return [annView autorelease];
}
}
```

I think if it doesn't work make use of `isEqual:` instead of `==`.